# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is installed, still no support for CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, css, service-pack

I've downloaded the latest version of Visual Studio 2010's Service Pack 1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691). However, after I extracted the files, installed the SP1, and restarted the whole OS, still I don't get support for CSS3 and HTML5 in VS2010.

Have you experienced the same problem? Anyone has any idea?

Update: HTML5 and CSS3 support is promised in these links (and of course, many more could be found):

1. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/27/html5-amp-css3-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx)
2. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2011/06/16/html5-and-css3-support-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
3. And [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingTheWebStandardsUpdateHTML5SupportForTheVisualStudio2010Editor.aspx)

And also I've installed **Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1**, but still no success.

Comment: What is the problem? Did Microsoft promise that SP1 would support HTML5 and CSS3?

Comment: Yeah @jalf. Just search for VS2010 CSS3 and HTML5 support and you'll find out.

Comment: Down-voter, please provide a valuable feedback. Have courage.

Comment: Since you're the one asking the question, why don't *you* search for those keywords, and post the facts *here* for us to make it easy to answer your question?

Comment: It seems you've now solved your own problem.  To benefit anyone else who comes across your question, could you please post your solution as an answer?

Comment: How says that I've solve my problem? What made you @LukeWoodward to think that? I still have the problem. I only updated the question because `jalf` wanted that.

Comment: Perhaps have you looked at this: [Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83)?  It looks like you have it listed as your third option already...

Comment: Yeah, but after installing that, still the support is not there.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: you didn't say in your question that you'd installed the Web Standards Update.  By adding links to pages about it, it seemed to me that you had found the reason why the HTML5 and CSS3 support was missing.  If you have installed it and the relevant support is still not there, you have a genuine question.  Bottom line: if you have installed this update, however, make it clear in your question that you have.

Comment: Saeed, it's not clear to everyone whether you've installed just the VS2010 SP1 patch, or if you've installed that *and* the Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

visual studio 2010 is not suopporting HTML5 and CSS3. you need to install 
[Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83)

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Tools->Options->Text Editor->HTML->Validations Select Target As HTML5
Also for CSS on Home VS screen near run button select combobox as css 3.0
it will definetly solve ur problem.