# Any one tell me Why css3.0 is not shown in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why visual Studio is not show css3.0 it always shows css2.1.
i have searched various blog didnt found anything.
Some stackover flow link are also there -

[1.See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938674/visual-studio-2010-sp1-is-installed-still-no-support-for-css3-and-html5)

Comment: Have you followed the advice on that post (installing web standards update, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with visual studio 2010 sp1 it is not showing css3 it only shows css2.1.
As this issue is raised in microsoft and they are solving it in the next release
With reference to this i am attaching a link
[Chk it here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/655432/no-css-3-shown-in-dropdown-on-vs-2010-sp1)

[Another One](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/12/02/new-css-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx)